# Can I use Firebase for email and hashed passwords

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, password-protection

Can I use Firebase database for username, email and password keeping.

Is it safe to use is there a decryption for fire-base or do I need to create that myself.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to manage your user account information like email/password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is integrated with the google authentication system, it uses SHA-1 to encrypt data on its own database. So if you just use the built in Firebase Auth, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create your own authentication since Firebase is already offering it. To achieve this, i recomand you reading the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

You don't need to create or maintain somethig, Firebase will handle for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks ^^ yeah i have just started learning firebase and saw there was loads more then just realtime database, will try the authentication and see if i can get it to work :D

Comment: new here so hard know xD

Comment: No problem. Hope you'll figure it out how to do it.